# Qt paths in resource system

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I want to add Qt translation file `qt_ru.qm` as a resource in my application, `QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath)` returns path: `D:\Programming\tools\Qt\5.5\msvc2013\translations`. If I try to add file with resource editor it says that file is outside of project directory and suggest to copy it. But I don't want to do this. Is it possible to substitute any Qt built in variable pointing to the translation path?
Something like:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file alias="qt_ru.qm">%QtPathToTranslation%/qt_ru.qm</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This translation file is meant to be deployed along with Qt. You are not meant to add it manually to your application's resources. Since you're using a dynamically linked build of Qt, you're already deploying many files in a specific folder structure, the translations belong with that deployment.

Comment: To be honest I think an author of an original question wants to deploy custom translation for his own application but for some reasons referencing qt_ru.qm, as I can't see any reasons to adjust default translation files.. so what he needs to do is to deploy own file and install this translation.

Comment: I am trying to minify deploying, because deploying Qt5 application is terrible in term how much shit I have to copy with my binary. So I would prefer to agregate translations, rather then use it in "native" Qt way

Comment: @Jeka There's no point to such "minifying". Qt will only open *one* of its translation files, according to locale. Deploying them as resources vs. individual files saves you next to nothing in terms of space. If you bundle them all as resources, they'll get mapped to the executable's address space and potentially they may get unnecessarily fetched from disk if application prefetch is in active. **Sometimes leaving things as files on the filesystem is the right thing to do, and this is such a case.** Why are you so concerned about file count? Your installer should handle it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You would better deploy it with [windeployqt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html#the-windows-deployment-tool) and let Qt use it in its "native" way.